# All video calls have latency

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, video

I have Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS on core i7, 32GB RAM, GeForce RTX2080Ti machine and all video calls are terrible - I am not able to have a video call with Slack, Google Meet or Zoom. I am able to attend the meeting and clearly see everything, but people have been complaining that when I speak, they have a delay.

I have also tried to connect via different browsers - Chrome and Mozilla Firefox but there is no difference.

Does anyone know what could cause the issue? The machine otherwise seems to be working fine and I haven't noticed any freezing or other issues that might be the cause for video calls issues. Also, I have fiber optics - have tested the connection right now and the speed is 48Mbps/45Mbps download/upload.

Comment: Are you using an Xorg session or Wayland? `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE`. Do you have the latest nvidia driver installed and in use? `glxinfo  | grep "client glx vendor"`. What audio device are you using? Is it a bluetooth microphone or some other headset?

Comment: x11, the glxinfo returns "client glx vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation". The microphone I believe is not a problem, I am using webcam mic.

Comment: What type of webcam? Is it directly attached to the computer or via a USB hub? Do you have any firewall or traffic shaping enabled? Could your ISP be aggressively traffic shaping? Could you test via a VPN and see if that avoids the issue?

Comment: it is a USB webcam. Usually, as there are issues with PC, I connect to the meeting with my phone through same Wi-Fi (same ISP). Therefore, the ISP is not causing the issues. I believe it is related either to some package I have installed on Ubuntu or drivers. It worked well about two months ago but I can't determine the exact snapshot and therefore I find it hard to diagnose the issue.